# Explicit check in method returning if object is nil?

Tags: objective-c

If I have a method like below:

```
-(BOOL)shouldResize {
    return _view != nil;
}
```

where _view is a pointer to an object, is the explicit nil check necessary/recommended, or is it sufficient to simply do:

```
-(BOOL)shouldResize {
    return _view;
}
```

I'm wondering if any strange behavior might pop up in casting the pointer to a BOOL, like in the example here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/bool?language=objc

(I guess you could also do `return !!_view`, right?)

Comment: FYI - Your second set of code is why you must never directly compare a `BOOL` variable with `NO` or `YES`. Simply do `if (someBool)` or `if `(!someBool)`. Using `if (someBool == YES)` or `if (someBool == NO)` or similar with `!=` may fail in a difficult to find bug.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the tip! Seems kinda broken though that a bug like that should arise in the first place.

Comment: What bug? The problem is only when you treat `BOOL` as zero and non-zero. `BOOL` should only ever be `NO` and `YES`, not zero and non-zero. The only bug here is your 2nd code example where you try to treat an object pointer as a `BOOL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on platform or architecture, `BOOL` may be equivalent to `signed char`. Therefore, `return _view` is not safe. The actual pointer value of `_view` will be truncated to a single byte. This byte is quite likely to be 0 even if `_view` is not `nil`. In that case, the code would return false when it should be true.

`return _view != nil` is safe and reasonable. Using `return !!_view` is correct and may or may not be suitable depending on the coding standards of your team. In some places it's the idiomatic way of "normalizing" a boolean expression. Others may find it too-clever-by-half and "ugly" (as expressed in other answers here).

Comment: +1 for the even just the first paragraph alone — returning `_view` itself truncates everything but the last byte, which can evaluate to 0. This is a very subtle bug that is rare enough to "work" in most cases but fail seemingly randomly.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the impartiality in your answer (: Just to clarify if i did something like return 4294967040 (ff ff ff 00), that would evaluate to false?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer "return _view != nil" for readability. The method returns a boolean and so I prefer that that is obvious from the code in the method.

In your case the second option (return _view) will work too.

"return !_view" I find ugly.

Answer (score 0):

The type BOOL is defined differently in 32 bit and 64 bit modes, so the behaviour is different. Therefore returning _view instead of _view != nil is a bug.

Take a hint from Swift (which you will have to do soon anyway). In Swift, self.view != nil would be the only legal way. Thank heavens.

As an example how dangerous being clever can be, "return !_view" is not just ugly, it is wrong. It does the opposite of what was requested.

Comment: The question did not propose using `return !_view` but `return !!_view`. It's not wrong. Ugly is in the eye of the beholder. Also, the question is about Objective-C and Swift isn't relevant.

Answer (score -1):

Simply returning the View will automatically handle if the view is nil or not. If its nil it will return 'NO' and 'YES' otherwise.So the second version of the shouldResize is enough.

As per me the best practice is to have an explicit nil check in order to have a clear understanding, better maintainability and avoid surprise.

Comment: Returning the view will not necessarily produce a true value when the view is not `nil`. See my answer for the reason why.

Comment: The 1st paragraph of this answer is wrong. There will be no automatic conversion of the object pointer to the values `NO` or `YES`. It just so happens that `NO` and a `nil` value ultimately are both forms of `0` but that's a long way from an automatic conversion.